# How to change tmux border size

Tags: macos, tmux, iterm2

I'm using

```
set -g window-style 'bg=default'
set -g window-active-style 'bg=#262626'
```

to highlight active pane in tmux and just same foreground for active/inactive borders

```
set -g pane-border-fg '#4d5057'
set -g pane-active-border-fg '#4d5057'
```

and I got this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FIyZ.png), so, as you can see there is a big sized border, which has terminal default background and it looks awful, so im trying to find way to reduce border size in tmux to 1px or something like this.

Actually it looks like a padding but it's not, if we'll try to set border bg to red, for example, we'll get this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsCYk.png).

As additional information, I'm using Mac OS and iTerm2 as terminal, but same problem presented even in default terminal for me.

**So, the question is:** how to reduce border size to 1px or make border bg transparent (not default, which equals terminal bg)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The borders are drawn by regular box-drawing characters in your terminal, so there is no way to make a border only 1px wide. The border will always be 1 character wide and 1 character tall, since it is drawn with characters.

A terminal application like iTerm may have the ability to draw at a pixel-perfect level and create multiple terminal windows to draw different panes, but this is because it has access to your OS or window system's low-level drawing commands. But tmux runs inside a terminal, and it only has one terminal window to work with. This is why it's limited to using normal terminal characters to draw borders.